# Bluetooth 4 (BLE) seems impossible to access on many devices (eg HP 15-d004au laptop)

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wish to write C/C++ code to communicate between a `HP 15-d004au` laptop and a `DISTO D510 laser measuring device`, which requires *[Bluetooth 4 Low Energy](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/low-energy-tech-info.aspx)* (BLE).

The laptop is supposed to have Bluetooth 4, and indeed I can pair with my device via Windows 8.1, but I can't access it in C/C++.

If I call `BluetoothIsVersionAvailable()`, the highest version it returns true for is 2.1, not 4.0 as required for BLE.

- What's the deal?
- Is this the wrong API to be using, or is it a configuration problem on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that even though BluetoothIsVersionAvailable() said the laptop only has support for up to Bluetooth 2.1, the other API calls still function, so I was able to get it working anyway.

Thanks,
Rob.